# What threats involve in cache miss

Tags: cryptography, attacks, threats, timing-attack, caching

What are the possible consequences of a cache miss? In other word, is it possible that a cache miss could cause a security threat?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you thinking about a specific threat? How about a specific cache?

Comment: Don't cross-post please

Comment: In what context? "Cache miss" may occur in several situations (I would see more threat in a cache *hit*, actually - more of a privacy issue than a security threat, perhaps).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, cache misses can be used in timing attacks.

Place an octet string on a page boundary, validate from left to right. If a cache miss occurs than everything up to the cache miss is correct, because otherwise the verification would have stopped (hence: always test all characters of a password / PIN etc.). A cache miss is more likely to be detected than simply counting the bytes that are validated as a cache miss will take many more CPU cycles (hundreds) instead of just a few.